# Vue router incrementing my route params id by plus one

Tags: vue.js, parameters, vue-router, increment, router

I am trying to change the id in my route by plus one of the current id whenever you press on a button. I am building a questionaire with True / false buttons and whenever a user presses a button it should go to the next id like so `/question/1` > `/question/2`. I have tried returning the current `this.$route.params.id++` in my computed lifecycle hook, like so:

```
nextQuestion() {
   return this.$route.params.id++;
}
```

But this results in the following error:

`Unexpected side effect in "nextQuestion" computed property`

My `<router-link>` looks like this:

```
<router-link :to="`/question/${nextQuestion}`">
...
</router-link>
```

I've tried also to replace `return this.$route.params.id++;` with `return this.$route.params.id + 1;` but this (logically) just adds the number to the end instead of incrementing it.

What would be the right way to approach this?

Comment: `return parseInt(this.$route.params.id)+1` so you don't mutate the param but return a mutated copy.

Comment: `return this.$route.params.id + 1;` should work fine, isn't that what you want? When user click on the link he will get to the next question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Turns out Vuex automatically parses `this.$route.params.id` as  string instead of Number. I solved it by using javaScript Number() method. In your case this would be:

```
nextQuestion() {
   return (Number(this.$route.params.id++));
}
```

or alternatively say your route view is `post/question/1`, you can add a handler to your button like so:  `@click="$router.push(nextQuestion)"`then in your  computed lifecycle hook, do this:

```
nextQuestion() {
    return "post/question/"  + (Number(this.$route.params.id) + 1)
}
```