# Problem going from one profile/:id to another using Vue js Dynamic Route Matching

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, dynamic-routing

my route is as:

```
`path: '/apps/user/user-view/:userId',
name: 'app-user-view'`
```

I also have  `<router-link> :to="{name: 'app-user-view', params: { userId: $route.params.userId [+1] }}"</router-link>`  which I want to take me to the next user (user/1 to user/2)

and `<router-link> :to="{name: 'app-user-view', params: { userId: $route.params.userId [-1] }}"</router-link>` which I want to take me to the prev user (user/2 to user/1)

it's not working, though. What am I doing wrong? Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a simple syntax issue... I'll admit I'm firing from the hip without testing, but I think it should be something more like this:

`<router-link :to="{name: 'app-user-view', params: { userId: $route.params.userId + 1 }}">Next User</router-link>`

Assuming that works though, you might want to create a computed property to make those objects for you and get them out of the markup (template) It will make everything a little cleaner.
Also consider safety measures like stopping at 0, dealing with 'gaps' from deleted users, etc...

Comment: Thank you Ashley, I was able to get a breakthrough. For some reason, Vue doesn't automatically parse params.values as number. the + operator results into a concat() as in 2+1 parses 21 instead of 3. I instead used += and queried the object id rather than the route param. Like I've https://stackoverflow.com/a/63786320/11283381